# Pass Parcelable argument with compose navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to pass a parcelable object (`BluetoothDevice`) to a composable using compose navigation.

Passing primitive types is easy:

```kotlin
composable(
  "profile/{userId}",
  arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") { type = NavType.StringType })
) {...}
```

```kotlin
navController.navigate("profile/user1234")
```

But I can't pass a parcelable object in the route unless I can serialize it to a string.

```kotlin
composable(
  "deviceDetails/{device}",
  arguments = listOf(navArgument("device") { type = NavType.ParcelableType(BluetoothDevice::class.java) })
) {...}
```

```kotlin
val device: BluetoothDevice = ...
navController.navigate("deviceDetails/$device")
```

The code above obviously doesn't work because it just implicitly calls `toString()`.

Is there a way to either serialize a `Parcelable` to a `String` so I can pass it in the route or pass the navigation argument as an object with a function other than `navigate(route: String)`?

Comment: you can JSON serialize your object to String then back

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Warning:**
[Ian Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) is an Android Developer Advocate and he says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059149/how-pass-parcelable-argument-with-new-version-of-compose-navigation) that pass complex data structures is an anti-pattern (referring the documentation). He works on this library, so he has authority on this. Use the approach below by your own.

**Edit:** Updated to Compose Navigation `2.4.0-beta07`

Seems like previous solution is not supported anymore. Now you need to create a custom `NavType`.

Let's say you have a class like:

```
@Parcelize
data class Device(val id: String, val name: String) : Parcelable
```

Then you need to define a `NavType`

```
class AssetParamType : NavType<Device>(isNullableAllowed = false) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): Device? {
        return bundle.getParcelable(key)
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): Device {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, Device::class.java)
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: Device) {
        bundle.putParcelable(key, value)
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using `Gson` to convert the object to a JSON string. But you can use the conversor that you prefer...

Then declare your composable like this:

```
NavHost(...) {
    composable("home") {
        Home(
            onClick = {
                 val device = Device("1", "My device")
                 val json = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(device))
                 navController.navigate("details/$json")
            }
        )
    }
    composable(
        "details/{device}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("device") {
                type = AssetParamType()
            }
        )
    ) {
        val device = it.arguments?.getParcelable<Device>("device")
        Details(device)
    }
}
```

**Original answer**

Basically you can do the following:

```
// In the source screen...
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments = 
    Bundle().apply {
        putParcelable("bt_device", device)
    }
navController.navigate("deviceDetails")
```

And in the details screen...

```
val device = navController.previousBackStackEntry
    ?.arguments?.getParcelable<BluetoothDevice>("bt_device")
```

Comment: For anyone using this solution note the difference between currentBackStackEntry and previousBackStackEntry on either side of the navigate call. Otherwise you'll waste 20 mins looking for your missing data... ;0)

Comment: Did you check if this approach works across process death?

Comment: This solution will not work if we pop up (`popUpTo(...)`) back stacks on `navigate(...)`.

Comment: @nglauber It works, but after that if you try to navigate again with different button for example without puting a parcelable, you'll get the old parcelable. So the way around would be puting a null parcelable.

Comment: Note that this won't survive process death. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182194894#comment6

Comment: This does not work for me: with `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha01` `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments` the value of `arguments` is `null` for me and it is `val` therefore cannot be reassigned

Comment: Wait, this basically overwrites the current route's / screen's args, and the next screen looks them up after navigation not from itself, but from the parent. This feels like a hack. What happens when the system needs the original args the parent got for whatever?

Comment: People don't parse your params to JSON, it is not performant. it's even on the main thread :pulling_my_hear:

Comment: @goldy1992 use this         navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putParcelable("key", value)

Comment: It is a bad practice. Despite on I celebrate all efforts to make it possible, it is discouraged by Android design. Here is the response with details from of one of Google|Android engineers with reference to the official documentation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059149/how-pass-parcelable-argument-with-new-version-of-compose-navigation

Comment: all of that looks ugly

Comment: @dead_can_dance that's why it's ugly and it's better not use it

Comment: the app is lagging and freezing when I add `navArgument("device") {  type = AssetParamType() }`

Comment: Do NOT use navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putParcelable("key", value). If the currentbackstackEntry doesnt have any arguments already, nothing will happen! @MohammadHosseinKalantarian

Comment: you can use `backEntry.savedStateHandle`, `backEntry.arguments` is blocked from reassigning

Answer (score 36):

I've written a small extension for the NavController.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.navigation.*

fun NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    args: Bundle,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null
) {
    val routeLink = NavDeepLinkRequest
        .Builder
        .fromUri(NavDestination.createRoute(route).toUri())
        .build()

    val deepLinkMatch = graph.matchDeepLink(routeLink)
    if (deepLinkMatch != null) {
        val destination = deepLinkMatch.destination
        val id = destination.id
        navigate(id, args, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
    } else {
        navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
    }
}
```

As you can check there are at least 16 functions "*navigate*" with different parameters, so it's just a converter for use

```
public open fun navigate(@IdRes resId: Int, args: Bundle?)
```

So using this extension you can use Compose Navigation without these terrible deep link parameters for arguments at routes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Looks nice but I get a nullpointer when I try it.

Comment: Best answer. You are much better than googler.

Comment: Can you improve it and how to use it?

Comment: Please specify how can we can get data on next composable where we are heading towards?

Comment: Best answer.

Hint: Don't use 
arguments = listOf() in the destination it will cause a crash if you're passing Parcelable or Serializable data types

Comment: Cant upvote enough 

Comment: does it survive process death?

Answer (score 7):

Here's my version of using the `BackStackEntry`

Usage:

```kotlin
composable("your_route") { entry ->
    AwesomeScreen(entry.requiredArg("your_arg_key"))
}
navController.navigate("your_route", "your_arg_key" to yourArg)
```

Extensions:

```kotlin
fun NavController.navigate(route: String, vararg args: Pair<String, Parcelable>) {
    navigate(route)
    
    requireNotNull(currentBackStackEntry?.arguments).apply {
        args.forEach { (key: String, arg: Parcelable) ->
            putParcelable(key, arg)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> NavBackStackEntry.requiredArg(key: String): T {
    return requireNotNull(arguments) { "arguments bundle is null" }.run {
        requireNotNull(getParcelable(key)) { "argument for $key is null" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. use NavGraph#findNode to get the destination
2. use destination's id to navigate, the method has a `args: Bundle?` parameter

```
val destination = navController.graph.findNode("YOUR_ROUTE")
if (destination != null) {
  navController.navigate(
  destination.id,
  bundleOf("key" to value)
  )
}
```

Comment: save time a lot time. thank you

Answer (score 7):

I've come up with this solution:

```
fun NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    args: Bundle,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null
) {
    val nodeId = graph.findNode(route = route)?.id
    if (nodeId != null) {
        navigate(nodeId, args, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
    }
}
```

This identifies the registered route by ID in the nav graph, completely bypasses the deep link mechanism and falls back to the original approach.

Register your route in the NavGraphBuilder like this:

```
composable(
    route = "MyRoute",
) {
    MyScreen(
        navController = navController,
        myArgument = it.arguments?.getParcelable("myParcelableArg")
    )
}
```

And navigate like this:

```
navController.navigate(
    route = "MyRoute",
    args = bundleOf(
        "myParcelableArg" to MyParcelable()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can pass an argument like this

```
val data = DetailScreenArgument(title = "Sample")

navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.apply {
   set("detailArgument", data)
}

navController.navigate(Screen.DetailScreen.route)
```

and get the argument in the destination like this

```
val detailArgument = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<DetailScreenArgument>(
    "detailArgument"
)
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't put value with type class TranslateModel into saved state

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to pass Custom Object to another composable using navigation graph

Comment: is your data class parcelable?

Comment: Yes, I have already make it parcelable

Answer (score 4):

I get a weird bug when I implement the top answer to this question. Like I have the following Parcelable to pass between two screens of my Jetpack Compose app:

```
@Parcelize
data class EdgeParcelable(
    val node: NodeParcelable?,
    val cursor: String?,
) : Parcelable
```

And as the accepted Answer says I have implemented a custom NavType:

```
class EdgeParcelableType : NavType<EdgeParcelable>(isNullableAllowed = false) {

    override val name: String
        get() = "edge"

    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): EdgeParcelable? {
        return bundle.getParcelable(key)
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): EdgeParcelable {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, EdgeParcelable::class.java)
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: EdgeParcelable) {
        bundle.putParcelable(key, value)
    }
}
```

And in my Composable function where I create the NavHost I have:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(viewModel: MyViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = { MyTopAppBar(
            currentScreen=currentScreen,
            canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
            navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() }
        ) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "home",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = "home") {
                val lazyPagingItems = viewModel.Items()
                HomeScreen(
                    lazyPagingItems = lazyPagingItems,
                    onTownClicked = { edge: EdgeParcelable ->
                        val json = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(edgeParcelable))
                      
                     navController.navigateSingleTopTo("hotspots/$json")
                    },
                    modifier = ...
                )
            }
            composable(
                route = "hotspots/{edge}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("edge") {
                        type = EdgeParcelableType()
                    }
                )
            ) {
                val edgeParcelable = it.arguments?.getParcelable<EdgeParcelable>("edge")
                HotspotsScreen(edgeParcelable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above crashes my Application when I add the lines:

```
val bsEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentScreen = bsEntry?.destination?.route ?: "Home"
```

Adding the above lines make the Composable become:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(viewModel: MyViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    // Adding these causes a problem...
    val bsEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = bsEntry?.destination?.route ?: "Home"

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = { MyTopAppBar(
            currentScreen=currentScreen,
            canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
            navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() }
        ) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "home",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = "home") {
                val lazyPagingItems = viewModel.Items()
                HomeScreen(
                    lazyPagingItems = lazyPagingItems,
                    onTownClicked = { edge: EdgeParcelable ->
                        val json = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(edgeParcelable))
                     navController.navigateSingleTopTo("hotspots/$json")
                    },
                    modifier = ...
                )
            }
            composable(
                route = "hotspots/{edge}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("edge") {
                        type = EdgeParcelableType()
                    }
                )
            ) {
                val edgeParcelable = it.arguments?.getParcelable<EdgeParcelable>("edge")
                HotspotsScreen(edgeParcelable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Passing my Custom NavType with the following line of code:

```
arguments = listOf(navArgument("edge") { type = EdgeParcelableType() } )
```

now crashes my app, by rendering it unusable. The app seems to choke on itself, almost like, the Navigation API does not really understand the new Custom `EdgeParcleableType()` or perhaps something is missing that remains to be added to make this `EdgeParcelableType` work well with the Navigation API.

I was only able to solve the problem by changing the type above to StringType as follows:

```
arguments = listOf( navArgument("edge") { type = NavType.StringType }
```

And passing around strings in the rest of the Composable as follows:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(viewModel: MyViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    // Using NavType.StringType allows this work...
    val bsEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = bsEntry?.destination?.route ?: "Home"

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = { MyTopAppBar(
            currentScreen=currentScreen,
            canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
            navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() }
        ) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "home",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = "home") {
                val lazyPagingItems = viewModel.Items()
                HomeScreen(
                    lazyPagingItems = lazyPagingItems,
                    onTownClicked = { edge: EdgeParcelable ->
                        val json = Uri.encode(Gson().toJson(edgeParcelable))
                     navController.navigateSingleTopTo("hotspots/$json")
                    },
                    modifier = ...
                )
            }
            composable(
                route = "hotspots/{edge}",
                arguments = listOf( navArgument("edge") {
                        type = NavType.StringType
                    }
                )
            ) {
                val edgeParcelable = Gson().fromJson(Uri.decode(it.arguments?.getString("edge")), EdgeParcelable::class.java)
                HotspotsScreen(edgeParcelable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my app worked like a Charm. Sorting this took me like 2 days of trial and error and searching so I hope this can help someone out there if faced with a similar issue...

Comment: I had the same issue, the only fix is to use object and not class https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245406008#comment3

Answer (score 3):

The backStackEntry solution given by @nglauber will not work if we pop up (`popUpTo(...)`) back stacks on `navigate(...)`.

So here is another solution. We can pass the object by converting it to a JSON string.

Example code:

```kotlin
val ROUTE_USER_DETAILS = "user-details?user={user}"


// Pass data (I am using Moshi here)
val user = User(id = 1, name = "John Doe") // User is a data class.

val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(User::class.java).lenient()
val userJson = jsonAdapter.toJson(user)

navController.navigate(
    ROUTE_USER_DETAILS.replace("{user}", userJson)
)


// Receive Data
NavHost {
    composable(ROUTE_USER_DETAILS) { backStackEntry ->
        val userJson =  backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("user")
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(User::class.java).lenient()
        val userObject = jsonAdapter.fromJson(userJson)

        UserDetailsView(userObject) // Here UserDetailsView is a composable.
    }
}


// Composable function/view
@Composable
fun UserDetailsView(
    user: User
){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that works also by adding the Parcelable to the correct `NavBackStackEntry`, **NOT the previous entry**. The idea is first to call `navController.navigate`, then add the argument to the last `NavBackStackEntry.arguments` in the `NavController.backQueue`. Be mindful that this does use another library group restricted API (annotated with `RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)`), so could potentially break. Solutions posted by some others use the restricted `NavBackStackEntry.arguments`, however `NavController.backQueue` is also restricted.

Here are some extensions for the `NavController` for navigating and `NavBackStackEntry` for retrieving the arguments within the route composable:

```kotlin
fun NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null,
    args: List<Pair<String, Parcelable>>? = null,
) {
    if (args == null || args.isEmpty()) {
        navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
        return
    }
    navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
    val addedEntry: NavBackStackEntry = backQueue.last()
    val argumentBundle: Bundle = addedEntry.arguments ?: Bundle().also {
        addedEntry.arguments = it
    }
    args.forEach { (key, arg) ->
        argumentBundle.putParcelable(key, arg)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null,
    arg: T? = null,
    
) {
    if (arg == null) {
        navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
        return
    }
    navigate(
        route = route,
        navOptions = navOptions,
        navigatorExtras = navigatorExtras,
        args = listOf(T::class.qualifiedName!! to arg),
    )
}

fun NavBackStackEntry.requiredArguments(): Bundle = arguments ?: throw IllegalStateException("Arguments were expected, but none were provided!")

@Composable
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> NavBackStackEntry.rememberRequiredArgument(
    key: String = T::class.qualifiedName!!,
): T = remember {
    requiredArguments().getParcelable<T>(key) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Expected argument with key: $key of type: ${T::class.qualifiedName!!}")
}

@Composable
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> NavBackStackEntry.rememberArgument(
    key: String = T::class.qualifiedName!!,
): T? = remember {
    arguments?.getParcelable(key)
}
```

To navigate with a single argument, you can now do this in the scope of a `NavGraphBuilder`:

```kotlin
composable(route = "screen_1") {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(
                route = "screen_2",
                arg = MyParcelableArgument(whatever = "whatever"),
            )
        }
    ) {
        Text("goto screen 2")
    }
}
composable(route = "screen_2") { entry ->
    val arg: MyParcelableArgument = entry.rememberRequiredArgument()
    // TODO: do something with arg
}
```

Or if you want to pass multiple arguments of the same type:

```kotlin
composable(route = "screen_1") {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(
                route = "screen_2",
                args = listOf(
                    "arg_1" to MyParcelableArgument(whatever = "whatever"),
                    "arg_2" to MyParcelableArgument(whatever = "whatever"),
                ),
            )
        }
    ) {
        Text("goto screen 2")
    }
}
composable(route = "screen_2") { entry ->
    val arg1: MyParcelableArgument = entry.rememberRequiredArgument(key = "arg_1")
    val arg2: MyParcelableArgument = entry.rememberRequiredArgument(key = "arg_2")
    // TODO: do something with args
}
```

The key benefit of this approach is that similar to the answer that uses Moshi to serialise the argument, it will work when `popUpTo` is used in the `navOptions`, but will also be more efficient as no JSON serialisation is involved.

This will of course not work with deep links, but it will survive process or activity recreation. For cases where you need to support deep links or even just optional arguments to navigation routes, you can use the `entry.rememberArgument` extension. Unlike `entry.rememberRequiredArgument`, it will return null instead of throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: `addedEntry.arguments = it` cannot be reassigned, maybe use putParceable??

Comment: This broke after a new version of compose navigation was released (it used to be var not val). The problem with using putParcelable is that it requires the arguments field not to be null (it's nullable). I've had to put a temporary hack in to set it through reflection if it's null. I recommend finding another solution. Either find another navigation library that's less dogmatic about forcing developers to model nav routes as URLs, or conform to the dogmatism forced on us by the team behind this and restructure your code to pass IDs to nav routes, then lookup the data you need using IDs.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Add the name of the data sent in the route

```
const val NEWS_DETAILS = "NEWS_DETAILS/{article}/{name}"
```

2 - Create dataClassParcelable

```
@Parcelize
data class ArticlesModel(
    @SerializedName("author")
    val author: String?,
    @SerializedName("content")
    val content: String?,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String?,
    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    val publishedAt: String?,
    @SerializedName("source")
    val source: Strins?,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String?,
    @SerializedName("url")
    val url: String?,
    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    val urlToImage: String?
):Parcelable
```

3 - Submit the required data

```
    fun NavController.openNewsDetails(article: ArticlesModel,name:String) {
        currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.apply{

             set(
                 "article",
                 article
             )

             set(
                 "name",
                 name
             )
         }

        navigate(ScreenConst.NEWS_DETAILS)
    }
```

4 - Reading information and sending them to a new screen

```
          composable(
                    route = ScreenConst.NEWS_DETAILS
                ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            
                    val article = 
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<ArticlesModel("article")
                    val name=
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<String>("name")
            
                    if (article==null && name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        return@composable
                    }
            
                    DetailsScreen(
                        article = article,
                        name = name
                    )
            
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code works for me for passing Parcelable argument with compose navigation:

```
composable(BottomNavigationScreens.SocialNetwork.route) {
...
onNavigateToRecipeDetailScreen = {
                                    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("recipe", it)
                                    navController.navigate(BottomNavigationScreens.RecipeDetails.route)
                                }
}

composable(BottomNavigationScreens.RecipeDetails.route) { backStackEntry ->
                        val recipe = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Recipe>("recipe")
...
}
```

In this approach, you set the Recipe object in the savedStateHandle of the current back stack entry using `savedStateHandle?.set("recipe", it)` and then navigate to the "recipe_detail" destination using `navController.navigate(BottomNavigationScreens.RecipeDetails.route)`

`navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Recipe>("recipe")` to get the Recipe object.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and basic way to do is as below

1.First create the parcelable object that you want to pass e.g

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
    val name: String,
    val phoneNumber:String
) : Parcelable
```

2.Then in the current composable that you are in e.g main screen

```
 val userDetails = UserDetails(
                            name = "emma",
                             phoneNumber = "1234"
                            )
                        )
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.apply {
                            putParcelable("userDetails",userDetails)
                        }
                        navController.navigate(Destination.DetailsScreen.route)
```

3.Then in the details composable, make sure you pass to it a navcontroller as an parameter e.g.

```
@Composable
fun Details (navController:NavController){
val data = remember {
        mutableStateOf(navController.previousBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getParcelable<UserDetails>("userDetails")!!)
    }
}
```

N.B:  If the parcelable is not passed into state, you will receive an error when navigating back

Comment: looks very ugly

Answer (score 1):

My approach with `Moshi`:

Routes

```
sealed class Route(
    private val route: String,
    val Key: String = "",
) {
    object Main : Route(route = "main")
    object Profile : Route(route = "profile", Key = "user")

    override fun toString(): String {
        return when {
            Key.isNotEmpty() -> "$route/{$Key}"
            else -> route
        }
    }
}
```

Extension

```
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.navigation.*
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi

inline fun <reified T> NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    data: Pair<String, T>,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null,
) {
    val count = route
        .split("{${data.first}}")
        .size
        .dec()

    if (count != 1) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }

    val out = Moshi.Builder()
        .build()
        .adapter(T::class.java)
        .toJson(data.second)
    val newRoute = route.replace(
        oldValue = "{${data.first}}",
        newValue = Uri.encode(out),
    )

    navigate(
        request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
            .fromUri(NavDestination.createRoute(route = newRoute).toUri())
            .build(),
        navOptions = navOptions,
        navigatorExtras = navigatorExtras,
    )
}

inline fun <reified T> NavBackStackEntry.getData(key: String): T? {
    val data = arguments?.getString(key)

    return when {
        data != null -> Moshi.Builder()
            .build()
            .adapter(T::class.java)
            .fromJson(data)
        else -> null
    }
}

@Composable
inline fun <reified T> NavBackStackEntry.rememberGetData(key: String): T? {
    return remember { getData<T>(key) }
}
```

Example usage

```
data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
)

@Composable
fun RootNavGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "${Route.Main}",
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "${Route.Main}",
        ) {
           Button(
              onClick = {
                  navController.navigate(
                      route = "${Route.Profile}",
                      data = Route.Profile.Key to User(id = 1000, name = "John Doe"),
                  )
              },
              content = { Text(text = "Go to Profile") },
        }

        composable(
            route = "${Route.Profile}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(name = Route.Profile.Key) { type = NavType.StringType },
            ),
        ) { entry ->
            val user = entry.rememberGetData<User>(key = Route.Profile.Key)

            Text(text = "$user")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my own solution: https://github.com/usmonie/compose_navigation_with_parcelable_arguments

With my solution, you will be able to get parcelable values directly into the composable function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had to pass a string that contains slashes, and since they are used as separators for deep link arguments I could not do that. Escaping them didn't seem "clean" to me.

I came up with the following workaround, which can be easily tweaked for your case. I rewrote `NavHost`, `NavController.createGraph` and `NavGraphBuilder.composable` from `androidx.navigation.compose` as follows:

```
@Composable
fun NavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: Screen,
    route: String? = null,
    builder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
) {
    NavHost(navController, remember(route, startDestination, builder) {
        navController.createGraph(startDestination, route, builder)
    })
}

fun NavController.createGraph(
    startDestination: Screen,
    route: String? = null,
    builder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
) = navigatorProvider.navigation(route?.hashCode() ?: 0, startDestination.hashCode(), builder)

fun NavGraphBuilder.composable(
    screen: Screen,
    content: @Composable (NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
) {
    addDestination(ComposeNavigator.Destination(provider[ComposeNavigator::class], content).apply {
        id = screen.hashCode()
    })
}
```

Where Screen is my destination enum

```
sealed class Screen {
    object Index : Screen()
    object Example : Screen()
}
```

Please note that I removed deep links and arguments since I am not using them. That will still allow me to pass and retrieve arguments manually, and that functionality can be re-added, I simply didn't need it for my case.

Say I want `Example` to take a string argument `path`

```
const val ARG_PATH = "path"
```

I then initialise the NavHost like so

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.Index) {
    composable(Screen.Index) { IndexScreen(::navToExample) }

    composable(Screen.Example) { navBackStackEntry ->
        navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString(ARG_PATH)?.let { path ->
            ExampleScreen(path, ::navToIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I navigate to `Example` passing `path`

```
fun navToExample(path: String) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.Example.hashCode(), Bundle().apply {
        putString(ARG_PATH, path)
    })
}
```

I am sure that this can be improved, but these were my initial thoughts.
To enable deep links, you will need to revert back to using

```
// composable() and other places
val internalRoute = "android-app://androidx.navigation.compose/$route"
id = internalRoute.hashCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `nglauber` suggestion, I've created two extensions which are helping me a bit

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> NavHostController.getArgument(name: String): T {
    return previousBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getSerializable(name) as? T
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
}

fun NavHostController.putArgument(name: String, arg: Serializable?) {
    currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putSerializable(name, arg)
}
```

And I use them this way:

```
Source:
navController.putArgument(NavigationScreens.Pdp.Args.game, game)
navController.navigate(NavigationScreens.Pdp.route)

Destination:
val game = navController.getArgument<Game>(NavigationScreens.Pdp.Args.game)
PdpScreen(game)
```

Comment: `previousBackStackEntry?.arguments?` => `arguments` is null

Answer (score 0):

Since the **nglauber's** answer work when going forward and does not when navigating backward and you get a null. I thought maybe at least for the time being we can save the passed argument using **remember** in our composable and be hopeful that they add the Parcelable argument type to the navigating with the route.

the destination composable target:

```
composable("yourRout") { backStackEntry ->
                backStackEntry.arguments?.let {
                    val rememberedProject = remember { mutableStateOf<Project?>(null) }
                    val project =
                        navController.previousBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getParcelable(
                            PROJECT_ARGUMENT_KEY
                        ) ?: rememberedProject.value
                    rememberedProject.value = project
                    TargetScreen(
                        project = project ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("parcelable was null"),
                    )
                }
```

And here's the the source code: to trigger the navigation:

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments =
            Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable(PROJECT_ARGUMENT_KEY, project)
            }
        navController.navigate("yourRout")
```