# My view recompose itself muitple times after changing state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i am working on compose project. I have simple login page. After i click login button, loginState is set in viewmodel. The problem is when i set loginState after service call, my composable recomposed itself multiple times. Thus, navcontroller navigates multiple times. I don't understand the issue. Thanks for helping.

My composable :

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        val email by viewModel.email
        val password by viewModel.password
        val enabled by viewModel.enabled

        if (viewModel.loginState.value) {
            navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
              popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
                 inclusive = true
              }
            }
        }

        LoginHeader()
        LoginForm(
            email = email,
            password = password,
            onEmailChange = { viewModel.onEmailChange(it) },
            onPasswordChange = { viewModel.onPasswordChange(it) }
        )
        LoginFooter(
            enabled,
            onLoginClick = {
                viewModel.login()
            },
            onRegisterClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.RegisterScreen.route)
            }
        )
    }
```

ViewModel Class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginRepository: LoginRepository,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    val email = mutableStateOf(EMPTY)
    val password = mutableStateOf(EMPTY)
    val enabled = mutableStateOf(false)
    val loginState = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun onEmailChange(email: String) {
        this.email.value = email
        checkIfInputsValid()
    }

    fun onPasswordChange(password: String) {
        this.password.value = password
        checkIfInputsValid()
    }

    private fun checkIfInputsValid() {
        enabled.value =
            Validator.isEmailValid(email.value) && Validator.isPasswordValid(password.value)
    }

    fun login() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = loginRepository.login(LoginRequest(email.value, password.value))
        loginRepository.saveSession(response)
        loginState.value = response.success ?: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not cause side effects or change the state directly from the composable builder, because this will be performed on each recomposition.

Instead you can use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). In your case, [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) can be used.

```kotlin
if (viewModel.loginState.value) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
            popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I think that much better solution is not to listen for change of `loginState`, but to make `login` a suspend function, wait it to finish and then perform navigation. You can get a coroutine scope which will be bind to your composable with `rememberCoroutineScope`. It can look like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun login() : Boolean {
    val response = loginRepository.login(LoginRequest(email.value, password.value))
    loginRepository.saveSession(response)
    return response.success ?: false
}
```

---

Also check out Google engineer thoughts about why you shouldn't pass `NavController` as a parameter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69060224/3585796) (*As per the Testing guide for Navigation Compose ...*)

---

So your view after updates will look like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    onLoggedIn: () -> Unit,
    onRegister: () -> Unit,
) {
    // ...
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LoginFooter(
        enabled,
        onLoginClick = {
            scope.launch {
                if (viewModel.login()) {
                    onLoggedIn()
                }
            }
        },
        onRegisterClick = onRegister
    )
    // ...
}
```

And your navigation route:

```kotlin
composable(route = "login") {
    LoginScreen(
        onLoggedIn = {
            navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
                popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
        },
        onRegister = {
            navController.navigate(Screen.RegisterScreen.route)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: LaunchEffect works perfectly, i have tried it but looks like i was using it wrong. Thanks for the help and advice about testing!

Comment: @BerkayKireçci you're welcome=) have you tried making your function suspend too? I really think it's much cleaner solution.

Comment: But i still don't get why does view recompose itself multiple times despite changing state once. Is this how compose works or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @BerkayKireçci from the code I see everything else seems fine. You can try adding `print` to see if it recomposes after adding `LaunchEffect`(obviously print should be outside of `LaunchEffect`). It shouldn't

Comment: I logged inside and outside LaunchEffect and there is one log inside it as exptected. But after onLoggedIn() works, it's still logging outside it. This is why i am confused. It looks  like:                                                                                                                                             ->"if"   ->"launcheffect"  ->"if"   ->"if"

Comment: I've checked on a sample code, and yes it looks like "rendering" two more times after the `navigate`. Not sure if that's a bug, anyway your view can be recomposed many times for many reasons, that's not something bad, you just shoudn't perform any heavy calculations inside view builder anyway.