# Can not pass parcelable object in compose navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

i am developing side-project with compose and I am interested in Compose navigation. the thing that I want is to pass Parcelable object from one Composable screen to another. so the navigation is like this :

```
composable(
        route = Screen.DetailsScreen.route,
        arguments = navArgument(PARAMETER_MOVIE_KEY) {
            NavType.ParcelableType(Movie::class.java)
        }
    ) {
        DetailsScreenGuide(navController, it)
    }
```

when navigating from Home Screen, I put parcelable object to `NavController.currentBackStackEntry`.

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putParcelable(
    "movieArgument",
    homeScreenNavGraphDataModel.movie
)
navController.navigate(route) // here, route = "movieDetails/movie"
```

and then, before calling the MovieDetails composable Screen, I try to get the movie object from `navController.previousBackStanEntry`.

```
val movie = remember {
    navController.previousBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getParcelable<Movie>(
        "movieArgument"
    )
}
```

but here, the `movie` variable is null and I can not receive the object. (the navigation is working and it's inflating MovieDetails composable function

can you help me with debugging these code snippets or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Have you look at this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610003/pass-parcelable-argument-with-compose-navigation/65619560#65619560

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Parcelable argument with compose navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610003/pass-parcelable-argument-with-compose-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. I used the below code and it's working for me

```
fun NavController.navigate(
    route: String,
    args: Bundle,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras? = null,
) {
    val linkRequest = NavDeepLinkRequest
        .Builder
        .fromUri(NavDestination.createRoute(route).toUri())
        .build()

    graph.matchDeepLink(linkRequest)?.apply {
        navigate(destination.id, args)
    } ?: navigate(route, navOptions, navigatorExtras)
}
```

Hint: Don't use arguments = listOf() in the destination it will cause a crash if you're passing Parcelable or Serializable data types

So the destination shoudn't be like this

```
composable(
  "movies/{movieDetails}",
  arguments = listOf(navArgument("movie") { type = NavType.ParcelableType(Movie::class.java) })
) {...}
```

It should be simply like this

```
composable(
  "movies/{movieDetails}"
) {...}
```