# How to pass argument of type NavType.ParcelableArrayType in Android Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am migrating from XML to Compose Navigation. Now I'm trying to pass an array of enums as an argument. My enum class looks like this,

```
@Parcelize
enum class MyEnum : Parcelable {
    Option1,
    Option2
}
```

This is how I define an argument in an XML file,

```
<argument
   android:name="enumArg"
   app:argType="com.test.MyEnum[]"
   app:nullable="false" />
```

And I was passing it by calling a function like this

```
navController.navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(enumList.toTypedArray())
```

Now, in the Jetpack Compose way, `MyEnum` class looks still the same and I defined my argument in the composable destination like this:

```
navArgument(name = "enumArg") {
   type = NavType.ParcelableArrayType(MyEnum::class.java)
   nullable = false
}
```

but the `navController.navigate()` function throws an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'enumArg' in argument bundle. [Lcom.test.MyEnum; expected.

I'm sure that I'm passing `Array<MyEnum>`. How should I pass these arguments? I can't find any example of ParcelableArrayType usage.

Comment: the answer here can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610003/pass-parcelable-argument-with-compose-navig